# GWT in CloudFoundry will it work?

Tags: java, gwt, cloud-foundry

My web application is made with Java, specifically with the Google Web Toolkit (GWT). The back-end used

- GWT RPC `RemoteServiceServlet`
- Hibernate/Java
- MongoDB (via Morphia)
- and other Java libraries

I really did not use any Spring framework at all, will my web application be able to be deployed in a CloudFoundry MicroCloud and in CloudFoundry.com hosting?

Will I be needing to reconfiguring my web application that has been tested and deployed in a Tomcat Server with MySQL and MongoDB database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT should not be an issue.
If you want to deploy a java web app not using Spring, you can deploy it as a java web app, then parse the VCAP_SERVICES manually to configure your data sources from the application.
See http://blog.springsource.org/2011/10/13/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-1-the-basics/ for details
https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples/tree/master/hello-java

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work?

In the event it wouldn't, that wouldn't be because of GWT at least: GWT-RPC runs in AppEngine, so there's no reason it wouldn't work in CloudFoundry.

Comment: Yes, I realized that this should be no problem, however its harder to make apps work with CloudFoundry than with App Engine though.